# Authentication plugin for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm migrating to Rails 3 and found that my `Restful_authentication` plugin gives me many problems. I never really liked it so I want to install another plugin instead but only found outdated plugins.

Is there any authentication plugin updated to work with Rails3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the best i've seen do far is [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). You could also try [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic), but i'd recommend the first one.

Used with an authorization gem like [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) will make your life way easier.

here's railscasts episode 209 [about devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) (also check 210 for more customizing)

i followed [this tutorial](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) to do a combination between cancan and devise, and it worked "just like that" (there is also a [part 2](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/) of that tutorial)

Comment: it looks way too complex. I only have: not logged in users, logged in users and administrator.

Comment: Devise works just as well for simple auth requirements as it does for complex ones.

Comment: I'm convinced, going thought the tutorial right now